# Targeting part of a comment using XPath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to use xpath to return the value "Vancouver", from either the comment or the text after it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The location li is always the first item but is not always present, and the number of list items after it varies for each item.

```
<item>
<title>
<description>
<!-- Comment #1 -->
<ul class="class1">
<li> <!-- ABC Location=Vancouver -->Location: Vancouver</li>
<li> <!-- More comments -->Text</li>
<li> text</li>
</ul>
</description>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will pull it from the text after the comment:

```
substring-after(//ul[@class='class1']/li[position()=1 and contains(.,'Location:')],'Location: ')
```

This specifies the first `<li>` inside the `<ul>` of class 'class1', only when it contains 'Location:', and takes the string after 'Location:'.  If you want to relax the requirement that it be the first li, use this:

```
substring-after(//ul[@class='class1']/li[contains(.,'Location:')],'Location: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't eloquent, and it could cause issues if your "Location: #####" were to change structurally, because this is a static solution, but it works for the above:

```
substring(//item//li[1],12,string-length(//item//li[1])-10)
```

And this returns the string equivalent, not a node. 
Rushed this one a bit, so I'll give a better solution with time but this is just something to think about...
(it just strips off "Location: " and returns whatever's after it..)

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
  substring-after(/*/description/ul
                       /li[1]/text()[starts-with(., 'Location: ')],
                  'Location: '
                  )
```

**To extract the location from the comment use**:

```
  substring-after(/*/description/ul
                       /li[1]/comment()[starts-with(., ' ABC Location=')],
                  ' ABC Location='
                  )
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "substring-after(/*/description/ul
                           /li[1]/text()[starts-with(., 'Location: ')],
                      'Location: '
                      )
     "/>
==========

     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "substring-after(/*/description/ul
                           /li[1]/comment()[starts-with(., ' ABC Location=')],
                      ' ABC Location='
                      )
     "/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<item>
    <title/>
    <description>
        <!-- Comment #1 -->
        <ul class="class1">
            <li>
                <!-- ABC Location=Vancouver -->Location: Vancouver
            </li>
            <li>
                <!-- More comments -->Text
            </li>
            <li> text</li>
        </ul>
    </description>
</item>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the results of the evaluations are copied to the output:**

```
Vancouver

==========

Vancouver
```